# Lua Roblox Studio Не меняется LabelText

Tags: lua, roblox

Написал скрипт для изменения текста через цикл, но в самом интерфейсе он не меняется, только в начале игры, хотя в proporites сам текст меняется, что мне делать

Сам скрипт находится в папке Workspace

Так же если поместить скрипт в сам Label то работать будет

````
local text = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.Frame.TextLabel
local name = 0
while true do 
    name += 1
    wait(1)
    text.Text = name
end```
````

Answer (score 0):

Может превратить число в строку?

`text.Text = tostring(name)`